# LayoutManager findCompletelyVisibleItemPosition returns wrong values

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have this code below, my adapter and my LayoutManager (Grid) are set above this code, but the values returned by

> findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition

are sometimes wrong (returns 1 instead of 5 for example)
I think this method is little bugged,

how can i get the good values ?

```
holder.mRecyclerViewImage.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (holder.mLastVisibleItems == -1)
                        holder.mLastVisibleItems = holder.mGridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    Log.d("myItemPosition", holder.mLastVisibleItems + "");
                    if (holder.mLastVisibleItems == 0 || holder.mLastVisibleItems == -1)
                        return;
                    int deleted = 0;
                    ArrayList<String> saveList = new ArrayList<>(listUrlImg);
                    while (holder.mLastVisibleItems + 1 < listUrlImg.size()) {
                        listUrlImg.remove(holder.mLastVisibleItems + 1);
                        deleted++;
                    }
                    holder.mRecyclerViewImage.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(saveList, listUrlImg, deleted));
                }
            }, 100);
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't 1 pixel off screen for the first item?

Comment: Does your adapter provide values available instantly or read them from a database / file? What if you choose a bigger delay, say, 1000 ms?

Comment: if i choose a bigger delay, returns the same values, and values are available instantly

Comment: It seems to me that the `RecyclerView` sometimes just can't finish measuring its values on time. What's the reason of calling `postDelayed(...)` on the `RecyclerView`? Maybe there's a better approach to the problem.

Comment: `postDelayed` avoid me to create a new  `Handler` and without this delay, the `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` returns everytime `-1`